# Samsung Hospitality Open Guide Sound Mirroring

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I have a hospitality TV, Samsung HAU8000. I want to open guide sound mirroring, like a screen mirroring.

This is code for open screen mirroring:

```js
var launchApplication = function(appName) {

    try {
        var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/view ",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            [
                new tizen.ApplicationControlData("deeplink", ["mobile_screenmirroring_1"])
            ]);

        // ApplicationControlDataArrayReplyCallback instance

        var appControlReplyCallback = {

            // callee sent a reply

            onsuccess: function() {
                console.log("inside success");
            },

            // callee returned failure

            onfailure: function() {
                console.log('The launch application control failed');
            }

        };

        tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, appName
            ,
            function() {
                console.log("[] success !!");
            }
            ,
            function(e) {
                console.log("[] error !!" + e.message);
            }
            , appControlReplyCallback
        );

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured :: " + error.message);
    }

};
```

can you help me to open the sound mirroring guide ?

I have changed

```js
[
    new tizen.ApplicationControlData("deeplink", ["mobile_screenmirroring_1"])
```

to

```js
[
    new tizen.ApplicationControlData("deeplink", ["mobile_soundmirroring_1"])
```

but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example shows the function for passing the ApplicationControlData to some *appName* application, but detailed context remains unknown for me. I will assume (basing on your question), that the same code works well for "mobile_screenmirroring_1" but not for "mobile_soundmirroring_1".

If above is true, I guess that the most possible reason for this is that *appName* application does not support handling the new key "mobile_soundmirroring_1" and just ignores it. You need to add proper code for handling it in your application.

To get more information about app control concept I suggest reading [the guide](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/app-management/app-controls/), and especially [this section](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/app-management/app-controls/#launching-applications-with-the-application-control) and [this section](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/app-management/app-controls/#receiving-and-replying-to-application-control-requests) which are related to handling app control data requests.

Answer (score 0):

From Tizen 6.0 upwards, SoundMirroring is called with

```
new tizen.ApplicationControlData("uri",["SoundMirroringGuide"]);
```

instead of

```
new tizen.ApplicationControlData("deeplink", ["mobile_screenmirroring_1"]);
```